# Magento 2 - Images randomly not loading on Product Page

Tags: frontend, product-images, products, magento-2.1.9

I am unsure what is causing this issue, but images are randomly not loading on the front-end of a live website. This issue came about yesterday and there doesn't seem to be an obvious fix.

Refreshing the page **SOMETIMES** fixes the issue, but another product will just randomly break.

[image: Image of the constant buffer]

[image: Stuck loading]

I have tried the following techniques:

- Flushing cache
- Flushing Image Cache
- Flushing JS/CC
- Reindexing
- Putting the site in maintenance mode and upgrading/compiling/deploying static files

I really do not want to run the "resize" function due to the size of the website.

Any tips? It's strange because it's completely random. I have tried it on multiple browsers with no changes.

I'm fairly new to Magento, so I apologize if I'm missing something that is obvious. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. A static-block from a module was breaking the JavaScript. Just disabled it and will find a work around.

Comment: Can you tell me what you static-block was the problem and how you fixed it?